# How can I explain this "Who" question simply to my student?

Tags: questions, subjects

I'm having trouble explaining to my student why you can't use "do/did" in the following sentence:

> Who taught you how to play the guitar?

He thinks that it's strange there is no "do/does" in the sentence. The grammar in that sentence feels strange to him.

I said that we can't say "Who does/did taught you how to play the guitar?", but he doesn't seem to understand.

I told him that "Who did you teach play the guitar?"(he made this sentence and asked if it has the same meaning) and "Who taught you how to play the guitar?" have a different meaning, but he doesn't understand.

Can anyone help out? :(

Comment: I suggest that you study [interrogative pronouns](http://www.write.com/writing-guides/general-writing/grammar/interrogative-pronouns/) when they are the subject of the sentence. e.g. "What happened next?" (No auxiliary is needed to form the question) "Who loves her?" (No auxiliary) Compare: "What DID YOU do next?" (YOU is the subject) and "Who DOES SHE love?" (SHE is the subject)

Comment: Related: [are there any questions that can be asked without a helping verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/261825/are-there-any-questions-that-can-be-asked-without-a-helping-verb) and this is a better post [“What keeps him going?” vs. “What does him keep going?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111912/what-keeps-him-going-vs-what-does-him-keep-going)

Comment: "Who _did_ teach you how to play the guitar?" is perfectly grammatical, but puts a lot of emphasis on the importance of finding the name of the tutor; it would only be used after say "I was taught by one of the greatest guitarists of the twentieth century."

Comment: Does your student understand that **you** in "Who taught you ..." is object, not subject?  Does he have the same problem with "Who taught *him|her|them*...?"?

Answer (score 5):

Rules for making *wh*-questions. First locate the missing information:

> 1. You taught ___?

Select the correct *wh*-word and insert it into this space:

> 2. You taught **who**?

If, and only if, you want to **move** the *wh-* word to the front of the sentence, invert the subject and the auxiliary verb. If there is no auxiliary verb, insert the verb *do*:

> 3. **Who** did you teach?

In this case we didn't have an auxiliary so we inserted *did*. Notice that it occurs before the subject, *you*.

---

Ok, lets try that with the Original Poster's sentence. First locate the missing information:

1. [_____] taught you to play the guitar.

Next choose the right *wh*-word:

2. **Who** taught you to play the guitar?

OK, well how about the third step. Hmmm. It doesn't look possible. We cannot **move** the *wh*-word to the front of the sentence. It's already there! For this reason we don't need to have subject-auxiliary inversion. And for that reason we don't need the word *do*. The question is already fully formed because the *wh*-word is already at the front of the sentence.

Answer (score 4):

Taught is the past tense.
You could not use "do" (present tense) with "taught" (past tense).

You also need to look at the person.
"Who taught you to play guitar" is directed at the student learning to play guitar. "Who did you teach to play guitar?" is directed to the guitar tutor.

Comment: Hello, Kieran. The question is _why_ [just] one of these uses do-support. OP is clear about _where_ this is needed.

Answer (score 4):

The question does not require an auxiliary verb because, technically, the full version should run something like this:

> Who [**is** the person that] taught you to play the guitar?

Answer (score 2):

You can start from your examples:

> Who(m) did you teach play the guitar?

and

> Who taught you how to play the guitar?

In the first example, **who**, or rather **whom**, is an interrogative pronoun in the accusative case, which, syntactically, is a direct object. So, here, you will simply have your student translate the English **who** into Russian and then select from its declension paradigm the form appropriate for the accusative case; then, finally, have him / her answer the question like this: *You taught **Ivan** to play the guitar*, in which case, as in the initial question, **Ivan**, which refers to **who(m)**, would also be in the accusative case.

As to the second example, have your student do the same as in the case of your first question. When, again, he / she answers the question by saying, ***Ivan*** taught you to play the guitar, your student will notice that **a.** Ivan once again refers to **who** in the question, and that **b.** unlike in the case of your first question, both **who** and **Ivan** are now in the nominative case because, syntactically, they are subjects.

In conclusion, on doing the replacement test:

> **Who** taught you how to play the guitar?

turns into

> **Ivan** taught you how to play the guitar.

As you can see, when doing this replacement test, the initial sentence, though interrogative in form, remains unchanged in its affirmative form. All that changes is **who** which gets replaced by **Ivan**.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great explanation! 

But I'm wondering why translate into Russian?? I'm American myself and my student is Japanese. (Probably should of mentioned that in the intro..! I apologize for that)

In any case, I'll try to explain it like that. Thank you!

Comment: esp. since Japanese has almost no irregular verbs (like 'taught').